# unique identifier For each browser using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, browser

I have a need to get  unique identifier from each browser using asp.net.i have been searched lot of web sites but i didn't get the result of that.till now i found following thing like Session.SessionId,passing session to navigated page not yet get what we are expecting.

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to do, instead of focussing on a specific solution?

Comment: I Need to Identify the user by his browser's unique Id.Is it possible?  (or)Any other Specific way to do in dot net programming? i need this solution because im  cross posting multiple application.

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by "unique id"?

Comment: Is there any Unique Id for Different browser's at the same time browsing a same page.

Comment: I still don't get it. Browsers do not have unique ids and you can't use the same server session across browsers. Do like @hans said and explain what you are trying to do, explain *why* you want such "unique id" or something, so maybe we can help you to find a solution.

Comment: if i login with an application ,that time i want keep track my id  in the application and then navigating to another website this time also I want keep the same id in that second application. Is it possible auto generate unique Id is possible by the browser.we cant pass the session to one application to another that is the reason we are looking for browser Identification

Answer (score 1):

No, we can not have unique identifier for each browser instance...

but requirement can be achieved with a work around using cookies.

**if both site are on sub domain of main domain you can access cookies easily.**

**if domain are different**

1. On site A add a hidden iframe to site C
2. Create a cookie on site C with GUID
3. send C's cookie to A using window.postMessage
4. Site A can then send that to server(using cookie or something else)
5. Do the same with Site B
6. Site B can also read C's cookie using iframe and window.postMessage

I think this solves your problem but still i am looking how to identify browser uniquely

Comment: What does this **NO!** mean?

Comment: actually No for the question we can not get any unique identifier for each browser instance. let me update the answer